# Upload Files to Sharepoint using Selenium Python While screen is locked

Tags: python, selenium, sharepoint, rpa

I try to upload files to Sharepoint suing  Selenium python but I have so many problem

1. sharepoint just have a button for open file chooser window so i can't use Sendkeys method
   [capture of sharepoint screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGVDV.png)

```
<button name="Files" data-automationid="uploadFileCommand" class="ms-ContextualMenu-link root-217" aria-label="Files" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="3" aria-disabled="false" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
```

Files

2. computer that be used to run it always locked
3. I can't use Sharepoint API because my company use MFA for sharepoint

is it a possible way to upload several files to sharepoint with all this conditions?

Comment: Do you see this css `input[type='file']` in that page ?

Comment: i did document.querySelector("input[type='file']") it's return null